# Bayesian or Frequentist goodnes of fit: depends on the data?

Tags: bayesian, goodness-of-fit, fitting, frequentist, astronomy

I'm working with the data of the real masses of exoplanets published in the catalogues (NASA, exoplanet.eu). Those catalogues update almost everyday by adding new exoplanet data or correcting some of data already published (because of the precision or anything else).

I need to set the probability density function (PDF) of the masses of the planets. In Frequentist statistics I must make use the data for estimating (using maximun likelihood estimation, for example) the parameters of the proposed PDF, make an histogram and use the frequencies for a fitting test like chi-square test for fitting data. Considering that every week the catalogues have more exoplanet data, the PDF of the masses may change... or remain the same. So, must I use Bayesian methods for fitting the data? In that case, how do I have to do it?

As I understand, in Bayesian Statistics I have to suppose something about the sample (a priori PDF) and use the Bayesian methods for finding what I'm looking for (a posteriori PDF). How can I set the a priori PDF?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is parametric and non-parametric density estimation. Do you need a parametric density or could you compute a non-parametric one? I don't quite understand why you think you need a Bayesian approach. What's wrong with re-computing a frequentist estimate when data is added? The Bayesians have a standard way of updating so that may be easier, however it doesn't guarantee you any better that your parametric model is appropriate (and you have to specify a prior on top of it). Using a test is not mandatory by the way (although if you assume a parametric density, testing may be of interest).

Comment: If you are trying to develop scientific information about exoplanets, rather than information about the evolution of observational technology, then any method, naively applied, will fail because it will not account properly for the extreme variability of inclusion probabilities and their changes over time.  (We just cannot detect the smaller and more distant planets but that ability is rapidly changing.) That issue is far more important to deal with at this juncture than choosing a prior distribution.